# Can I carry out a Propensity Score Matching with a general population of 90 observations and a treatment group of 20?

Tags: database, size, matching, propensity-score-matching

My population consists of 90 administrative zones that divide the city. Of those zones, only 20 received the treatment. After carrying out PSM, I have 17 zones in the treatment group and 17 in the control group, with a high level of balance on co-variables.

I know scholars recommend a minimum of 100 observations in each group, but considering the size of my population of interest (90), is it okay if I proceed with my research? I have already invested a substantial amount of work getting this far.